# Lagrange multiplier volume maximatisation

Tags: calculus

Using method of lagrange multiplier show that among all rectangular parallelepiped inscribed in a given sphere cube has the maximum volume

Comment: Have you made an image?

Comment: *Welcome to the site !*. As you are asked, use Lagrange multipliers. You must understand that, on this site, many people are ready to **help** you but no one will do your homework. Please show us what you did and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You will have $$V=abc$$ and $$4R^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$$. By AM-GM we get $$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}$$ so we get
$$\frac{4R^2}{3}\geq\sqrt[3]{V^2}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Yes I can do this now